# It's listcomps or genexps when no [] or () obvious exist

Tags: python, iterator, generator

When we use list comprehension like `[i for i in range(10)` we got a list, use generator expression like `(i for i in range(10)` we got a generator. If there are no `[]` or `()` obvious exist, and what we get? a list or generator?

```py
>>> max(i for i in range(10))
9
>>> max((i for i in range(10))
9
>>> max([i for i in range(10)])
9
```

So, I just want to know `max(i for i in range(10))` use list or generator when calculate max number?

Comment: Make a guess, then replace `max` with `type` to see if you were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max(x for x in ...)` is using a generator. Lists are always enclosed in square brackets: `[x for x in ...]`.

Answer (score 0):

It uses generator you can make a proof just writing a simple function like this one:

```
def guess_type(obj):
    print(type(obj))
```

and then calling the function with you generator:

```
guess_type(i for i in range(10))
guess_type((i for i in range(10)))
guess_type([i for i in range(10)])
```